# Grabbing the permissions from a TextChannel - Discord.js

Tags: discord, permissions, discord.js

Basically, I need to grab the permissions from the current text channel the user is in. I have already got the channel name, if I need to get the ID that should be pretty easy to do.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  let currentChannel = message.channel.name;
  let category = message.channel.parent;;
  message.guild.createChannel(currentChannel).then(mchannel => {
    mchannel.setParent(category).then(() => {
      message.channel.delete();
    });
  });
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "a.cleanchannel"
}
// Need the channel permissions to overwrite the new channel's permissions with the old ones
```

The expected results are that the channel should have the same permissions as the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use [`GuildChannel#permissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites) to create the new channel with the same permissions as the old one. For example...

```js
message.guild.createChannel(message.channel.name, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: message.channel.permissionOverwrites
});
```

However, it looks like you're trying to clone a channel. To help make that easier, there's a method built into Discord.js for it - [`GuildChannel#clone()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=clone). You can use it like so...

```js
message.channel.clone(undefined, true, true) // Same name, same permissions, same topic 
  .then(async clone => {
    await clone.setParent(message.channel.parent);
    await clone.setPosition(message.channel.position);
    await message.channel.delete();

    console.log(`Cloned #${message.channel.name}`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I didn't know about clone, it's really nice!

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind is that it doesn't keep the parent and position, so that's why you have to set them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver.